# How to pass text from Activity to Google Now search in Android

Tags: java, android, google-now

I have an activity with EditText and Button. When user is pressing the button i need to launch Google Now Search from my Activity and pass a text from EditText to make Google Now search for this text. How can i do this?

Comment: Use their API and call it in your application,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
String query = editText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.SearchActivity");
intent.putExtra("query", query);
startActivity(intent);
```

you can get more info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tasker/mOjAZjMreng/h5-KveRaDFcJ)