# Sending commands to voice assistant from Android app

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

In order to increase efficiency I want to send frequently used commands to Google Assistant from an Android app via script. E.g. "Ok, Google .

This is the code I use for calling Assistant from a Service:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

I have found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457906/sending-commands-to-google-assistant-using-script-instead-of-mic), which says that this is not possible for Raspberry Pi which uses Google Assistant SDK. Is it the same for Android apps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE: Does not work with Google Assistant. It only worked with Google Now.

Managed to make it work:

```
String command = "navigate home by public transport";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.SearchActivity");
intent.putExtra("query", command);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //necessary if launching from Service
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Source: [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156147/how-to-pass-text-from-activity-to-google-now-search-in-android)